# Why "51" > "6" is false (String > String) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, operators

Why "51" > "6" is false in JavaScript

```
"51" > "1" = true
"51" > "2" = true
"51" > "3" = true
"51" > "4" = true
"51" > "5" = true
```

But the below one is false,

```
"51" > "6" = false
```

Comment: Because `"5"` is less than `"6"`.

Comment: Adding to @tkausl's comment, you shouldn't compare numbers as strings. You will ALWAYS run into issues. Just do parseFloat()